# Стоит ли выключать Wake Lock в моём Android приложении?

Tags: java, android

Моё приложение должно поддерживать соединение с сервером 24 на 7. Сервер может отправить запрос в приложение в абсолютно любое время, расписания нет. При разрыве соединения, приложение пытается к нему снова подключится каждые 2 минуты, с расчетом на то что сервер может оказаться в сети в любой момент.

Напрашивается вопрос, а когда мне Wake Lock снимать и дать смартфону уйти в спящий режим? Если же снимать блокировку не нужно, то разве ОС не заблокирует приложение?

Comment: а в чем проблема использовать FCM? у вас Firebase через свой сервис будет поддерживать все то что вам нужно без лишней головной боли

Comment: мое приложение не работает с Google

Comment: Что-то я не очень понял логику, если вы будете снимать Wake Lock хоть когда-нибудь, то никакого "24 на 7" уже не получится, не?

Comment: Почему же? зачем WakeLock нужен когда пользователь включил экран? Я отключаю WakeLock когда экран включен

Comment: @D-ma что-то вы противоречите сами себе. Если пользователь включил экран, то никакого спящего режима не будет. Если пользователь выключил экран и вы включили Wake Lock, то никакого спящего режима опять не будет. В вопросе вы спрашиваете, когда дать смартфону уйти в спящий режим, а в итоге вы пришли к варианту «никогда», что-то я тогда не понимаю в чём вообще смысл вашего вопроса

Comment: @andreymal, я вопрос не правильно задал. Смысл вопроса нужно ли давать уходить смартфону в спящий режим, а если нет, то ОС разве не заблокирует моё приложение?

Comment: Вместо Wake Lock и прочих костылей необходимо переделать приложение так, чтобы оно не требовало постоянной работы в фоном режиме и всегда было готово к периодам простоя неопределенной продолжительности.

Answer (score -1):

Нашел ответ на другом форуме - см. [Сервис работает некорректно(Hasl.ru)](https://husl.ru/questions/626587?ysclid=ljw28gn8yg793768802).

Суть ответа - release нужно вызывать, когда экран блокируется. acquire - когда разблокируется.

Вот что касается будет ли приложение заблокированно если непрерывно блокировать режим бодровствования:

> непрерывное использование этой службы может привести к тому, что ваше приложение будет помечено новым диспетчером задач переднего плана в Android 13, см. [источник](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/understanding-wake-locks-in-android-13/).